# How is Allah worthy of worship?

Tags: salat, sharia, ibadah

I’m worshiping Allah and praying 5 times a day and I know the Attributes of Allah but just to know and ** to have a better faith, how is Allah worthy of worship?**
I know that Allah is the most merciful and the best giver but I want to know more about why Allah is the only worthy of worship.
(The answers won’t impact my worship, I will still be praying if He wants)

Answer (score 1):

**Why is Allah worthy of worship?**

- For being among the religion of Islam out of the 10,000 (false) religions in the world.
- For blessing you with caring Muslim parents
- For blessing you with good health
- For blessing you with the ability to learn, have a good education
- For blessing you with a house so you may seek safety, warmth, and protection in
- For blessing you with children (if you're married and a father/mother)
- For blessing you with siblings (if you have siblings)
- For letting you have food and water on the table
- For letting you have money to buy goods with
- For having a chance at life
- For being a guided Muslim on the path of Islam

I can keep going but I believe you get the point.

> "And He gave you of all what you asked of Him. And if you count the Favor of Allah, you will you be able to count them. Indeed, mankind is surely unjust and ungrateful." 
> **-Abraham 14:34**

So you see, Allah has given us so many blessings, the least we can do is thank Him for these blessings and not coming off as arrogant and/or ungrateful.

God does not need human worship. He didn't make humans out of a desire to pursue His glory. It would not lessen God's glory if no single person worshiped Him. God is self-sufficient. Humans, on the other hand, were born with needs and desires. As a result, it is humanity who deserves to worship God. Human beings must follow God's divinely revealed rules in order to honor and glorify him. God's obedience is the secret to happiness in this world and in the afterlife. The most logical and rational thing to do in life is to believe in and obey God.